# why doesn't spi1 in pi4j work?

Tags: pi-4, spi, pi4j

I'm trying to connect raspberry with another pcb via `spi`. It is connected via `spi1` port and I **can't change it**. So I have a python script that works well, so I can send and receive data. The python script:

```py
import RPi.GPIO
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import spidev
import time
import os


spi = spidev.SpiDev()

spi.open(1, 2)
spi.max_speed_hz =1000000
spi.mode = 0b00


try:
    while True:
        tx_list = [0x10]+ [228, 123, 145, 234, 221, 42, 212, 226] +[0]
        print(tx_list)
        rx_list=spi.xfer(tx_list)
        
        str_read = "".join([chr(_) for _ in rx_list])
        print(str_read)
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('exiting')
finally:
    spi.close()
```

But I need to work with `spi` using `java`, so I decided to use `pi4j` library. Then I wrote a simple program, that should do the same as the python script:

```java
import com.pi4j.io.spi.SpiChannel;
import com.pi4j.io.spi.SpiDevice;
import com.pi4j.io.spi.SpiFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SPI
{

    public static void StartSPI()
    {
        try {
            SpiDevice spi = SpiFactory.getInstance(
                    SpiChannel.CS1,
                    SpiDevice.DEFAULT_SPI_SPEED,
                    SpiDevice.DEFAULT_SPI_MODE);

            while(true)
            {
                byte[] rx = spi.write((byte)16, (byte)228, (byte)123, (byte)145, (byte)234, (byte)221,
                        (byte)42, (byte)212, (byte)226, (byte)0);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rx));
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. It returns only empty arrays like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What could be the reason of this? Thanks!

**Edit 1:** So I found `jdk.dio` library, but it is too difficult for me to install it to `rpi`. So the conclusion is: `java` is poor.

Answer (score 0):

Setting dtparam & dtoverlay in a program is futile.

These are instructions to Device Tree to configure the operating system at boot time.

Edit your config.txt.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/configuration.html#part3.1

Comment: thank you for your answer. I edited ```config.txt``` and removed command line calls from my code (also I will edit my question now). But it didn't help :( Java program still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In the Python code you are using SPI bus 1 and chip select 2.

In the Java you are using the default SPI bus (0) and chip select 1.

You need to use the bus and chip select appropriate for your wiring.

Comment: but how to do this? I tried to find a normal SPI classes and methods in pi4j but couldn't

Comment: I don't know Java.  You might need to ask at https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j-v2/discussions

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Pi4J are you using?

Examples with SPI can be found here:

- V1: https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/blob/master/pi4j-example/src/main/java/SpiExample.java
- V2: https://pi4j.com/documentation/io-examples/spi/